# Type 'SymbolConstructor' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am following an example in this [github repository](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-example/blob/master/Basic/constant/types.ts)

My code is

```
const TYPES = {
    UserService: Symbol("UserService")
};

export default TYPES;
```

Visual studio code intellisense gives the following error for the above code.

> message: 'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature. Type 'SymbolConstructor' has no compatible call
>   signatures.' at: '3,18' source: 'ts'

**Symbol definition**

```
interface SymbolConstructor {
    readonly iterator: symbol;
}
declare var Symbol: SymbolConstructor;
```

This symbol definition is defined in @types/node index.d.ts. When I navigate to the Symbol definition through visual studio code intellisense it took me to the file `@types/node index.d.ts.`

I just copy paste the code from the repository which I mentioned earlier. So there is no change. I also checked the packages which I installed just to make sure that I installed everything which is there in the repo.
Everything looks same.

I am very new to typescript. I looked into some of these links

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941061/ts2349-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature-type-typ) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727954/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature-type-has-no-compa). But I am not able to understand that. Can anyone please clarify on this why this error is coming ?

Comment: update the post with `Symbol` class

Comment: `SymbolConstructor` is not a class but an interface, so you are getting that error. what is the scenario elaborate I will give an alternate solution

Comment: I am just following the example from that GitHub link. Just to understand inversely.

Comment: That variable is been used like this `container.bind<UserService>(TYPES.UserService).to(UserService);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I did.

I looked into the repository [here](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-example). The only change is lies in the tsconfig file

In my tsconfig I had this line

> "types": ["reflect-metadata"]

So the compiler is able to look only the @types/node definitions. But when I remove this the compiler is able to find some other definitions from here `lib.es2015.symbol.d.ts`.

This file is present inside here

> /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.d.ts

Now that error is gone on the removal of "reflect-metadata" from types in my tsconfig file

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I found I had neglected to add `"lib": ["es6"]` to my `tsconfig.json` file.

There's a good description of this setting [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306295/4289902).